# How can I make links in an EditText clickable?

Tags: android, android-edittext, linkify

I have an `EditText` on Android I'd for which I'd like any embedded urls to be clickable. I used the `Linkify` class, which has turned them blue and underlined them. However, I can't figure out how to actually make them clickable.

Thanks!

Comment: I'd like to mention EditText links are already clickable by default - you just have to double-tap them to open a special menu.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

XML:

```
 android:linksClickable="true"
 android:autoLink="web|email"
```

JAVA:

```
TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewId);
textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(html));
textView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

Comment: This does not work for me. I used the XML version with no luck. The text looks like a link, but is not clickable.

Comment: Do u use `textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(html));`?

Comment: You don' need to use `Linkify.addLinks(textView, Linkify.ALL);` then.

Comment: This actually works! I was missing the `setMovementMethod()` call.

Comment: This works for TextView but the question is for EditText

Comment: etNote.movementMethod = LinkMovementMethod.getInstance()
etNote.setLinkTextColor(Color.parseColor("#077641"))

Answer (score 22):

For edit text I managed to get links clickable on the following way.
First i implemented a Custom MovementMethod as describe [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18541955/1651940)

Java

(Create your edit text from xml or context)

```
editText.setLinksClickable(true);
editText.setAutoLinkMask(Linkify.WEB_URLS);
editText.setMovementMethod(CustomMovementMethod.getInstance());
//If the edit text contains previous text with potential links
Linkify.addLinks(editText, Linkify.WEB_URLS);
```

Then to manage that the urls look like links while the user types

```
editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {


        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

                Linkify.addLinks(s, Linkify.WEB_URLS);

        }
    });
```

Comment: This is perfect. Is there any way to implement this with the ability to detect phone numbers and highlight them as well?

Comment: Yes @Collinux the class [Linkify](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/util/Linkify.html) supports 4 types: Web links, Phone numbers, emails and map addresses

Comment: Take note that, we should use `setLinksClickable(false);`, if we intent to have our own custom `CustomMovementMethod`.

Answer (score 0):

XML - Write it in your EditText

```
android:autoLink="web"
android:inputType="textWebEditText"
```

Comment: You could dramatically improve your answer by (1) formatting code as `code`, i.e., enclosing code in backticks, (2) elaborating on the connection between your XML and Java/Kotlin code and steps to actually make this work, and, (3) explaining how your approach improves upon [Kamil's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18219651/3410474) from 2013.

Answer (score 0):

> Hope this will help someone

```
val message: String = String.format(
        getString(R.string.message_content),
        firstNameEditText.text,
        lastNameEditText.text,
        dateTextView.text,
        timeTextView.text
    )

    val gMapURL = getString(R.string.google_map_location)

    // Setup my Spannable with clickable URLs
    val spannable: Spannable = SpannableString(gMapURL)
    Linkify.addLinks(spannable, Linkify.WEB_URLS)

    // Append a zero-width space to the Spannable
    val gText = TextUtils.concat(spannable, "\u200B")

    val finalText = TextUtils.concat(message, gText)
    messageContentEditText.setText(finalText)
```