# Android clickable url in EditText

Tags: android, url, android-edittext, clickable

Me and a friend of mine are creating a note application for Android. The user must be able to paste a url in the note and when he clicks it -> the browser opens. It has to be something like this: Some text URL more text. URL is clicked in the editText -> the browser opens. I searched for an answer but I didn't found it.

Comment: What did you search? Do you have any attempt at it? [This page may be helpful](https://www.google.com/search?q=clickable+url+in+EditText+android&oq=clickable+url+in+EditText+android&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60.7408j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8)

Answer (score -1):

XML:

```
 android:linksClickable="true"
 android:autoLink="web|email"
```

JAVA:

```
TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewId);
textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(html));
textView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

[reference] [How can I make links in an EditText clickable?][1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18219568/how-can-i-make-links-in-an-edittext-clickable)